# Пунктуация в предложении (1)

Tags: пунктуация

Прочитал такую фразу:

*Но вот однажды в 2002 году, весной, как сейчас помню, 5 мая, мы приехали на Пасху  в Васютино.*

Я добавил две запятые по сравнению с оригиналом, а именно выделил "5 мая" запятыми. В том, что хоть одна из этих запятых нужна, сомнений нету. ***Вопрос в том, обе нужны или всё же только одна из них.***  Вроде бы после "помню" никак её не опустишь, верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все не так. Не те запятые нужны. Пасха - она раз в году. Здесь "однажды" = "в некоторый год". Уже поэтому "в 2002...5 мая" - уточнение. Внутри этой конструкции запятые можно расставлять по-разному. Мне больше по душе такой вариант.

***Но вот однажды, в 2002 году(,) весной, как сейчас помню - 5 мая, мы приехали на Пасху в Васютино.***

При такой конструкции запятую в скобках я воспринимаю как необязательную и нежелательную, а в остальномполучается уточнение внутри уточнения.
Но тут дело авторское.

Можно эти уточнения считать "одноуровневыми", тогда ваш вариант (с учетом моего уточнения) актуален.

***Но вот однажды, в 2002 году, весной, как сейчас помню, 5 мая, мы приехали на Пасху в Васютино.***

Но очень уж стилистически неряшливо получается, избыточность явная в передаче "склероза" лирического героя.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus! Мне нравится Ваш вариант. Только о каком "склерозе" речь, не пойму что-то?..

Comment: Ну "склероз" - это ирония. То, что лирический герой вспоминает. Не помнит, а именно вспоминает, не очень уверенно..

Answer (score 0):

Когда? - весной! Когда? - пятого мая!

Одно уточняет другое.

А "как сейчас помню" - это вводное предложение, в своих запятых.

А без него могло бы быть:

"Однажды (зпт) в 2002 году (зпт) весной (зпт)  5 мая (зпт)..." - это ж всё обстоятельства времени, всё нанизано - от самого общего (однажды) к самому конкретному (числу).

Но после "однажды" запятая факультативна (остальные обязательны).

(И две нестрашные попутные ошибочки:

> Я добавил две запятых по сравнению с оригиналом, а именно, выделил "5
>   мая" запятыми.

Две запяты**е**; убрать зпт после "а именно".)

---

Розенталь. [**§ 96. Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxv.html#sect96.1):

> Обособляются слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих
>   слов.
>
> Чаще всего уточняющими являются обстоятельства места и времени.
>
> Например:
>
> а) В предместье, около боен, выли собаки (Чехов); За рекою, в
>   розоватом небе, ярко сверкала вечерняя звезда (Горький); Даже сюда,
>   через озеро, за километр, вместе с горячим воздухом, доносился гул и
>   треск (Гайдар);
>
> б) В полдень, в ясную, солнечную погоду, ничего нельзя вообразить
>   печальнее этой развалины (Тургенев); …Он встал по хозяйству рано, в
>   третьем часу утра, и теперь у него слипались глаза (Чехов); Сейчас,
>   поздней осенью, когда я живу в Москве, шкатулка стоит там одна в
>   пустых нетопленых комнатах… (Паустовский).
>
> В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться как
>   уточняющие или не как уточняющие; ср.: Далеко, в лесу, раздавались
>   удары топора (слушатель находится вне леса). – Далеко в лесу
>   раздавались удары топора (слушатель тоже находится в лесу).

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Точно, когда писал "две запятыХ", было подсознательное ощущение, что как-то неправильно написал, но не додумал.

Comment: И за "а именно" спасибо! Меня как раз смутило, что это перед глаголом, я залез на Грамоту, но неправильно воспринял их совет, т. е. решил, что у меня случай В. Главное, оставалось ощущение, что, может, эта запятая и не нужна. Опростоволосился, короче, по полной.)))

Comment: Всё дело в том, что я не дотумкал до того, что "как сейчас помню" — вводное выражение.

Comment: Тёмочка, это нестрашные ошибки, до Мотуса тебе далеко! У тебя остались сомнения, является ли пятое мае уточнением к весне?  § 96 кликабелен, там можно поподробнее всё рассмотреть. Или, использовав запрос "обособление уточняющих обстоятельств времени", поискать более очевидные примеры.